# Appned the value in array by removing the selected option or adding new options

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have an array of options like this

```
const objectArray = [
  { name: 'Option 1', cat: 'Group 1' },
  { name: 'Option 2', cat: 'Group 1' },
  { name: 'Option 3', cat: 'Group 1' },
  { name: 'Option 4', cat: 'Group 2' },
  { name: 'Option 5', cat: 'Group 2' },
  { name: 'Option 6', cat: 'Group 2' },
  { name: 'Option 7', cat: 'Group 2' },
];
```

My component is a functional component and I have used `useState` like this

```
var specializations = [];
const onSelectSpecialization = (event, value) => {
  specializations.push(value);
};
const onremoveSpecialization = (event, value) => {
  specializations.filter(
    (specializations) => specializations.name === value.name
  );
};
```

The Multiselect module I am using is multiselect-react-dropdown

```
<Multiselect
  options={objectArray}
  selectionLimit='5'
  onSelect={onSelectSpecialization}
  onRemove={onremoveSpecialization}
  style={{ height: 'auto' }}
  closeOnSelect='false'
  emptyRecordMsg='No specialization found'
  placeholder='Select upto 5 Specialization'
  displayValue='name'
  id='true'
/>;
```

I want final array in which there is only selected value appears, no values should be there if I removed them from the list as share in the screenshot

[see here for referenence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY22C.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the `useState` hook in the correct way.
Try to change your code like this:

```
const objectArray = [
  { name: 'Option 1', cat: 'Group 1' },
  { name: 'Option 2', cat: 'Group 1' },
  { name: 'Option 3', cat: 'Group 1' },
  { name: 'Option 4', cat: 'Group 2' },
  { name: 'Option 5', cat: 'Group 2' },
  { name: 'Option 6', cat: 'Group 2' },
  { name: 'Option 7', cat: 'Group 2' },
];

const [specializations, setSpecializations] = useState(objectArray);

const onSelectSpecialization = (event, value) => {
    setSpecializations(oldSpecializations => [ ...oldSpecializations, value])
};
const onremoveSpecialization = (event, value) => {
  const filteredSpecializations = specializations.filter(
    (spec) => spec.name === value.name
  );
  setSpecializations(filteredSpecializations)
};
```

As you can see now it is using the `useState` hook to update the `specializations` array.

Also, change your `MultiSelect` options to `specializations`:

```
<Multiselect
  options={specializations}
  selectionLimit='5'
  onSelect={onSelectSpecialization}
  onRemove={onremoveSpecialization}
  style={{ height: 'auto' }}
  closeOnSelect='false'
  emptyRecordMsg='No specialization found'
  placeholder='Select upto 5 Specialization'
  displayValue='name'
  id='true'
/>;
```

Comment: As you have mention  where have you defined oldSpecializations?                                                                                            
        const onSelectSpecialization = (event, value) => {
    setSpecializations(oldSpecializations => [ ...oldSpecializations, value])
};

Comment: The `setState` hook has an optional parameter that refers to the previous state.

Comment: So i do not have to define oldspecialization any where and use  [ ...oldSpecializations, value]) like this same as u mentioned?

Comment: It is a parameter that you get from the `setState` callback function. You don't need to declare it outside.

Comment: I did like what you said, but what is happening if  am selecting any value the value is getting appended in the  [specializations]  and when i am removing the value from list it is again getting appended in the [specialization]. I want values in an array which is only selected

Comment: 0: {name: 'Option 1', cat: 'Group 1'}
1: {name: 'Option 2', cat: 'Group 1'}
2: {name: 'Option 3', cat: 'Group 1'}
3: {name: 'Option 4', cat: 'Group 2'}
4: {name: 'Option 5', cat: 'Group 2'}
5: {name: 'Option 6', cat: 'Group 2'}
6: {name: 'Option 7', cat: 'Group 2'}
7: {name: 'Option 1', cat: 'Group 1'} 

This is the result i am getting when i select any value

Comment: 0: {name: 'Option 1', cat: 'Group 1'}
1: {name: 'Option 1', cat: 'Group 1'} 

This is the result i am getting when i remove the selected value

Comment: can you please explain?